# Record and Preview VB.Net Directshow

Tags: vb.net, directshow

I am using the GFPreview Sample code from directshow.net itself, I converted it to vb.net code, however, there is a following error when I select a device to use.

`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{08E3287F-3A5C-47E9-8179-A9E9221A5CDE} failed due to the following error : 80040154`

what does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It seems I have registered a 32-bit version of a DLL file that I used. Therefore, i only installed the 64-bit version of it. It now works.